# Bottle/Python - "IOError: [Errno 9] read() on write-only GzipFile object" when trying to decompress request body

Tags: python, gzip, bottle

I use Bottle to receive gzipped request body. When the size of the request is small, everything is fine. However, if the size of request body is a bit larger (say, >= 20kb), an IOError is thrown.

The following is the code used to read and decompress the request body:

```
@post("/receive")
def receive():    
    try:
        f = request.body
        g_f = gzip.GzipFile(fileobj=f)
        content = g_f.read()
        # other stuff on the content...
    except IOError, e:  
        # handle the error
```

The error message is:

```
[2015-09-07 16:27:27,967][ERROR   ] Failed to decompress gzipped data: [Errno 9] read() on write-only GzipFile object
127.0.0.1 - - [07/Sep/2015 16:27:27] "POST /receive HTTP/1.1" 400 756
```

Comment: does this also happen when you specify read only mode when creating the GzipFile object?

Comment: @Oz123 The compressed request body is generated by another program and sent as binary data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This problem is caused by the inheritance of the read/write mode of the fileobj used to create the `GzipFile` object.

If the size of the `request.body` is less than 20k, `Bottle` loads the whole binary data as a `StringIO` object. `GzipFile` deals with `StringIO` very well, everything works fine.

On the other hand, if the size of the `request.body` is larger than 20k, `Bottle` will use `tempfile` module to create a temporary file for this request body, for platform-consistency, the default mode of files created by `tempfile` is 'w+b'.

However, GzipFile determines if a file readable or not only by the mode string obtained by `hasattr(fileobj, 'mode')`, if this string is something like 'rxx', `GzipFile` considers it as readable, and vice versa. If the `read()` function of a non-readable `GzipFile` is invoked, an `IOError` will be thrown.

Since the mode of the file which will be used by the `GzipFile` is 'w+b', the `GzipFile` is still going to consider it as 'non-readable', so, boom! Error thrown. To fix this, just add the `mode` argument when creating the `GzipFile` object:

```
try:
    f = request.body
    g_f = gzip.GzipFile(fileobj=f, mode='rb')
    content = g_f.read()
    # other stuff on the content...
except IOError, e:  
    # handle the error
```